# How to optimize two related objective functions?

Tags: optimization, restrictions

Suppose we have two functions which are somewhat related in that if one increases, the other decreases in a non-linear fashion. The decision variables for one function may or may not be present for the other function. The goal is to find the optimal decision variables that maximizes one and minimizes other, so that there is a balance between the two. Of course, its an easy task to maximize one function, but the optimal values of the decision variables that maximizes the function may not be good for minimizing the second function.

EDIT:
Suppose the two objective functions are:

```
 f(a,b,c) = 30a + 2.5b - 90c 
 g(a,b,d) = 90d - 30a + 89b
```

The goal is to find `a,b,c` and `d` that maximizes f and minimizes g. 
Let's say the constraints are:

```
   a>0
   b>0
   c>10
   d>0
   a+b < 1000
   a+d >100
```

Comment: There are several approaches, would you mind using [edit] and including your objective functions of interest?

Comment: Edited and added some arbitrary functions and constraints.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency

Comment: Agree with @Sycorax.  Would start with that and see if that meets requirements in your application.  Related link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization

Comment: Is there any R implementation of the Pareto optimization?